# Spring Boot Redis: Distributed Caching of Objects from Backend Services for parallel consumer requests for the same Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, redis

i didn't know how to explain my challenge better in the title.

The current setup is, that I'm using Spring Rest Service as a "middleware layer" in order to transform the backend's data, which is a huge response, in a more "friendly" way.

This is the for example the structure of the backend:

```
public class Customer
{
   private String id;
   private String bankAccount;
   private String customerName;
}
```

The middleware is currently caching the response from the backend in redis.
It also has following endpoints:

```
public class ServiceController
{
   getBankAccountById(String id);
   getCustomerNameById(String id);
   getCustomerObjectById(String id);
}
```

All of the requests are producing a backend call for the customer object and cache it in redis, if no object is already present.

But in a multi-threaded environment and especially in an "cloud" / multi-instance environment if the consumer is doing n-requests (#1 getBankAccountById() #2 getCustomerNameById(), etc. in a parallel manner - exact same millisecond), that only one single request is fired against the "real" backend?

My Goal is something like putting a marker into redis that there will be an object of the type customer for a given id is in the cache in the near future, which results in blocking all other threads / threads of other instances in order to reduce backend calls.

My question, is there a simple or maybe an out of the box solution for that?

The only thing I found was the docs of Spring Boot and @Cacheable, which is not feasible, since it synchronizes the calls for a given Id within the same application, not service wide in a clustered environment.

And in addition to this, the backend is really slow (5-10 seconds per call), that the @Cacheable annotation is already passed by since it's starts writing to cache when the actual @Cachable Object is returned.

Thanks in advance,
Cheers Alex

//Edit:
I meant that @Cachable(sync=true) is only affecting the instance level and not a distributed level. Therefore it doesn't really make sense here from my understanding.

Comment: Did you come up with a simple solution for that by now? We have the exact same issue.

Comment: Found this: https://redislabs.com/blog/caches-promises-locks/. This looks "promising" ;-)

Comment: Give it a try: https://positivethinking.tech/insights/distributed-caching-using-redis-in-spring-boot-applications/

Answer (score 0):

You can try with @Cacheable(sync = true), which ensures that only Single thread is building cache and all the other threads can access the Cache instead of making a backend call.

Comment: This is not really useful in my case, since I'm within a clustered environment. And therefore Request A can happen on Server1 and Request B can be loadbalanced to Server B within the same millisecond.

Comment: Can you please paste the Redis configuration from your properties

Comment: simple straight forward:


`spring.redis.host=host
spring.redis.port=port`